# numbers issue after export mysql data to CSV

Tags: php, mysql, string, excel

when i get data from database and export it as a csv file i have following issues :

- the leading zero of the numbers dosnt show
- big numbers shows like this -> `1E+12`

how to force MS Excel to show all of my data as string by PHP

Comment: I think you'll need to change cell format via Excel.

Comment: i need to do this with php

Comment: When you import the CSV to MS Excel, you have the option to define formatting for each column... if you simply double click the CSV to open in MS EXcel, you are stuck with MS Excel's default formatting options

Comment: If you want a file to open on double-click with specific formatting, then you can't use CSV but need to use a recognised spreadsheet format (e.g. xls, xlsx, ods) with that formatting defined

Comment: Review your CSV using notepad or something similar. If it's OK there, then is Excel's fault.

Comment: yes this is a excel fault and i knew it

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use double quotes contain the numbers, like this:

```
if(is_numeric($column)) $column = '"'.$number.'"';
```

Answer (score 0):

This isn't a MySQL issue, it's an Excel thing.

This... might help: http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/office/forum/office_2007-excel/disabling-scientific-notation/943b8103-8c50-451d-8037-c697422e2307

But this question is more MS Office related than programming.

(or as comments suggested, use a file format that carries display formatting info, such as .xls)

Answer (score 0):

I format it as a string by concatenate it with spaces at its start and end.

`CONCAT(" ", database_number, " ") AS "Number For Excel"`.

Answer (score 0):

Kai's answer didn't quite work for me.  I ended up CONCATing an equals sign (still with the double quotes on either end) to the front and got the desired result.  Our users wanted to be able to copy and paste the number straight out of Excel into our UI.

```
CONCAT('="',too_long_number_field,'"')
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use number_formate() function to convert ...

View link

Function : number_format()
Syntax : number_format ( float $number , int $decimals = 0 , string $dec_point = ‘.’ , string $thousands_sep = ‘,’ )
Example to convert 6.90743E+11 to number use below code

number_format(6.90743E+11,0,'','') // outputs 690743000000